# Indices en Vistas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL con más de 50 tablas y cada uno tiene su indice, vistas, vistas de las vistas, procedimientos almacenados.

Mi pregunta es con respecto a las vistas, al momento de crear una vista con columnas de cierta tabla y una de esas columnas que agrego a la vista tiene un indice, ¿La vista se lleva tambien el indice de la tabla orginal?, Si no es asi quisiera saber la razon y como poder resolverlo.  :)

Mi codigo de vista es enorme, pero pondre un ejemplo de como las hago

```
CREATE VIEW sox AS 
    SELECT inicio, fin, nombre, categoria, activo FROM entrada 
        WHERE inicio = '2016-08-16';
```

Los indices estan en inicio y fin.

Comment: De la [doc MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html): _View processing is not optimized: -It is not possible to create an index on a view. -Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables)._ También: _Views do not have indexes, so index hints do not apply. Use of index hints when selecting from a view is not permitted._ Si necesitas traducción avisa.

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es **depende**, en que tipo de algoritmo se basa tu vista, si es `merge` o `temptable`. En el caso de que fuera merge, es decir, que toma en cuenta los índices y claves primaria **si haría uso del índice que mencionas.** **EDIT:** Podríamos hacer una muy buena pregunta y respuesta si eres algo más específico con la pregunta, aportas código de ejemplo, imágenes de la estructura a la que te refieres, etc.

Comment: ok ahora lo agrego